# About an unbounded normal product of one symmetric operator and one bounded positive operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a densely defined symmetric (unclosed) operator and let $B\in B(H)$ be positive.

I know that if $\overline{A}B$ is normal (where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$), then $AB$ need not be normal.

My question is: If $AB$ is normal, is it necessary that  $\overline{A}B$ remains normal? (notice that, thanks to the normality of $AB$, I have shown that $B\overline{A}\subset \overline{A}B$).

Cheers.